# automatically fill fields using a drop-down list

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a combo box which is linked with a table (products) and i need to fill fields automatically when the user select a value.
Datas in the fields are also from the table products.

Thanks

Comment: Comboboxes allow you to select a record. there is a wizard.

Comment: @Lucas: as you can see from the discussions below, your question is kinda unclear. What exactly do you want to fill? Unbound controls? Bound controls -- in table Products or another table (but then you would duplicate data... bad.) ?

Answer (score 1):

If your combobox row source is

```
SELECT ProdID, ProdName, ProdColor FROM Products
```

and column widths 0;3;0 (i.e. only ProdName is visible), you can use the AfterUpdate event to copy data from the combobox columns to other controls.

```
Private Sub cboProduct_AfterUpdate()

    Me!txtID = Me!cboProduct.Column(0)
    Me!txtColor = Me!cboProduct.Column(2)

End Sub
```

Comment: I am not sure why you would want to do this when the controls can have a control source set and be filled in automatically on selecting a record via the dropdown.

Comment: I assumed he wants to fill data into a new record (not table Products), not select an existing record. @Fionnuala

Comment: "Datas in the fields are also from the table products" suggest to me that it is a simple look-up. I think we have insufficient information :)

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way will be just to create yourself a myComboBox_SelectionChanged() event. Then within your method assign the values where you want them.

```
Private Sub myComboBox_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles myComboBox.SelectionChanged

     // Exact the selection here and put it in your table.

End Sub
```

Comment: The OP's did not include VB.Net in his tags.

Comment: yep, that's vba

Comment: Apologies.

Is it not simply a case of linking a cell then?

http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/combo-box.html

Create yourself a proxy cell to hold the value then reference your selection from the table?

Comment: nop, i need to  Auto fill fields based on selection in Combo Box from the same table

Comment: So that I understand;

You have a ComboBox whose input range is configured from one area of a table, and you want it's selection to auto update other values in the same table?